# I messed up my grub config

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, grub-customizer

I just upgraded from 23.04 to 23.10. I used grub-customizer to make my grub screen nicer, but after the upgrade, ubuntu menuentry disapeared. I manged myself to boot ubuntu. Now I want to go back to default grub old-fashion installation, but I think I'm making it worse.

I removed grub-customizer with  `apt purge grub-customizer`, but it left lot of files in `/etc/grub.d/`. So I run `rm -rf /etc/grub.d` and `apt-get install --reinstall grub-common`, but now I have an empty `/etc/grub.d`.

I have dualboot, ubuntu and windows. Ubuntu is in `/dev/nvme0p1n5`. Windows entry is still there, no problem.

```
# lsblk | grep -v loop
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
nvme0n1     259:0    0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   100M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0    16M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 699,4G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0   604M  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p5 259:5    0 231,4G  0 part /
```

Any hint?

Comment: You need a full reinstall of grub, not just grub-common. If boot, `sudo grub-install` If UEFI that uses ESP mounted in fstab and defaults for UEFI entries. If not booted then chroot into install or use Boot-Repair' advanced mode to totally reinstall grub. https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Thank you so much. I had to use boot-repair to completely reinstall Grub, and it resolved the problem. I apologize for the delayed response; I didn't find the time to address the issue earlier, and I haven't rebooted my PC during this period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to totally remove Grub-Customizer, and restore default grub scripts  in /etc/grub.d & settings in /etc/default/grub.

Most newer users using gui find Boot-Repair the easiest solution. but must be sure to boot live installer in same boot mode, now ususally UEFI, not old BIOS. How you boot live installer is both how it installs or repairs.

You can use Boot-Repair's advanced mode to choose what to reinstall and where.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

You also can run commands to manually uninstall Customizer & reinstall grub. UEFI version shown. When grub is un-installed, system will not boot. Make sure you have working live installer to make repairs if needed.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo update-grub
```

Make sure repositories are updated

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt purge grub-efi-amd64 grub grub-pc grub-common # if any file not there & error, re-run without that one file
sudo mv /boot/grub /boot/grub_backup
sudo mv /etc/grub.d /etc/grub.d_backup
sudo mkdir /boot/grub
sudo mkdir /etc/grub.d
sudo apt-get install grub-efi-amd64
sudo update-grub
```

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2492988&page=4