Cannot boot Windows from grub after upgrade to Kubuntu 24.10
today I upgraded to Kubuntu 24.10 from 24.04.
After the update I'm unable to boot to Windows 10 from GRUB, while it's still possible directly picking Windows Boot Manager from UEFI.
I've tried to relaunch sudo update-grub and got such results:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found theme: /boot/grub/themes/poly-dark-master/theme.txt
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.11.0-8-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.11.0-8-generic
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Error: invalid volume.
grub-probe: error: cannot find GRUB device for /dev/sdc1. Please check device.map.
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.11.0-8-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.11.0-8-generic
Found memtest86+ 64bit EFI image: /boot/memtest86+x64.efi
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Error: invalid volume.
grub-probe: error: cannot find GRUB device for /dev/sdc1. Please check device.map.
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done

After reboot still same happens I just got:
error, cannot load image and it returns to main GRUB menu, whats even strager I cannot then boot into kubuntu untill I restart the PC. It just begins to launch it and then returns to the main GRUB menu. After restart I can boot into Kubuntu just normally.
My grub config /boot/grub/grub.cfg here.
I'va Kubuntu and grub installed on /dev/sdb/, /dev/sdc/ is one of Windows striped disks. Windows is located on /dev/nvme0n1/.

you are using proxy files for grub from Grub Customizer. It replaces standard grub files with its versions. Best not to use it, but probably not issue as grub only boots working Windows. Windows updates may turn fast start up on, or hibernation or bitlocker. If you can boot directly from UEFI check those settings.

@oldfred I recreated it with Grub Customizer after update, but before it was clear Grub and still not worked. I'll check this hibernation or fast startup, but it seems quite unlikely as just before Kubuntu upgrade it was working fine.

That grub would not boot Windows would not be solved with Grub Customizer. Often better to just manually edit grub settings as not really that difficult, if you can type. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1491892/i-messed-up-my-grub-config

search launchpad.net for the files:
grub-efi-amd64_2.12-5ubuntu5.1_amd64.deb
grub-efi-amd64-bin_2.12-5ubuntu5.1_amd64.deb
grub-efi-amd64-signed_1.209.1+2.12-5ubuntu5.1_amd64.deb
grub-efi-amd64-unsigned_2.12-5ubuntu5.1_amd64.deb
install with dpkg and everything will work again

It's due to an issue in GRUB2 being non-compatible with non-NX shim which includes Windows 10 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/2084104
According to the maintainers the fix was prepared last week and will be available in oracular-updates in several days.
In the meantime you can boot windows directly from the UEFI boot menu as a temporary workaround.

Follow the instructions at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed then in a console sudo apt install -t oracular-proposed grub-common grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed grub-efi-amd64-unsigned grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub2-common
